# Could not Resolve method R on Imported Project. (In App Billing Version 3) in Android Studio .4.2

Tags: android, import, android-studio, in-app-billing

I imported the In app Billing V3 (The sample from Google). While changing the package in in android manifest or changing the target SDK of the program then rebuild, suddenly R method could not be found.

Anyone already encounterd this?

[image]

Android Manifest

```
    <!--
      Copyright (c) 2012 Google Inc.

      Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
      you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
      You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

      Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
      distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
      WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
      See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
      limitations under the License.
    -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.trivialdrivesamplemotok"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <!-- VERY IMPORTANT! Don't forget this permission, or in-app billing won't work. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.trivialdrivesample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Where did you put IInAppBillingService.aidl ?

Comment: It is a sample from google in app billing..  This is not a gradle project i think.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti It is found in com.android.vending.billing

Comment: Maybe if you rename a package, it is not just renaming the package on the manifest?

Comment: I think, i found the answer, when you change the package on android manifest, you should also refractor your folders. Android Studio don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml files ( the layouts ) plus the manifest xml file for errors any error in these xmls will prevent the project from generating the R file. plus make sure there is no elements in the layouts that require a higher SDK level than the one you selected as your target SDK.

Comment: This is a sample from google. I assume that there is no error on it. Well, I did double check and I think there is no error on it.